# I get an error (No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource) when I access my react app using Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, socket.io

I made a simple chat app using react and socket.io. It all went good,the app worked fine on localhost ,but when I deployed the app with Heroku ,I get the same error. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

This is how I connect to the server in the react app

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { SocketProvider } from 'socket.io-react';
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('https://react-zoichenger.herokuapp.com');
```

This is my nodejs server

```
const express =require('express')
const socket = require('socket.io')

var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())

const server = app.listen(4000,function(){
  console.log("Connected");
})

//Socket setup
const io = socket(server);


io.on('connection',(socket)=>{
  socket.on('sendMessage',(data)=>{
    console.log(data);
    io.emit('receiveMessage',data);
  })
  console.log('made socket connection')
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to modify your server-side code**

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, { origins: '*:*'});
```